# Pass parameters to SQL Script through Invoke-SQLCmd

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I've been provided a .sql script which will create a database. Within the script there is a variable which is used for the Database name.

```
:setvar DatabaseName database-name-1
```

Im calling the script from a pipeline which calls a PowerShell script which uses the Invoke-SQLCmd command in the following format

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -AccessToken $access_token -InputFile $DbInputFile -Variable $dbName
```

I've created the variable in the PowerShell as follows

```
$dbName = @("DBNAME=$db_name")
```

$db_name is just a string that contains the name of the DB I want to create.

Within the sql script I've tried using various combinations to use the $db_name as the database name

```
:setvar DatabaseName "`$(DBNAME)"
:setvar DatabaseName "$(DBNAME)"
:setvar DatabaseName $DBNAME
```

but whenever I run the pipeline is just uses the value specified, it doesn't expand the variable, so it would create a database name as $DBNAME or `$(DBNAME)

Im not sure what im doing wrong here, or if what I am trying to do is possible.

What I am expecting to see is the database created with the actual name defined within the $db_name variable.

Comment: Variables don't expand within variables. This restriction is not specific to `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, `sqlcmd.exe` behaves this way too. Because `:setvar` has the highest priority, you cannot use it to provide "defaults" that the external script should override. Leave out the `:setvar` directive and pass the variable directly as `"DatabaseName=$db_name"`. Of course this means the script will fail in a non-obvious way if this value is not supplied, but, well, that's `sqlcmd` for you. I still have no idea why someone thought it was a worthwhile idea to replicate it in PowerShell, warts and all.

Comment: Thank you - for the explanation - that sorted the issue!

Comment: I can't see how to mark that as an answer though